# Storing value on the server side on Startup()

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my app I have a functionality to upload an image. I want that if the user doesn't upload any image, the default gets uploaded. I have thought of storing the image in some folder and on the startup() the image must get store on the server side then I will fetch the id of the image so as to upload it as a defaut image as for e.g in the following code.

```
Template.modelView.helpers({
  thumbImg:function()
  {
    thumbImage = ThumbFiles.findOne({gFile:this._id});
    if (thumbImage) {
      return thumbImage;
    } else {
      // Return StartupImage id here
    }
  }
})
```

I have followed the question on the stackoverflow. I am getting the same error as mentioned there but I am unable to understand how to resolve it.

Comment: As far as I understand it (if I understand it) what you are trying could be solved better in another way. If you simply want to show a default image in case there is nothing found in your `ThumbFiles` collection a better way to go is to store this default image in your `public` folder on the server and simply get it from its static URL in your `else` part.

Comment: I have a folder both on client and server side, but yet  it is not working. It is not the picking the static link. I followed the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328807/what-is-the-meteor-server-side-path-to-public. But this is not working. Can you give any working example.

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure what your actual problem is but let's say you have an app running under `http://app.com` which has the local path `/home/meteoruser/app` on the server. All you would have to do now is to put a default image on the server under `/home/meteoruser/app/public/default.png` - this is now online available under `http://app.com/default.png`. In your template at some point you will already pull the the `src` of your returned `thumbImage` so all you have to do in your `else` clause is to create a dummy `thumbImage` object with the static `src` `http://myapp.com/default.png`.

Comment: I am able to access the image under http://app.com/default.png. But can you tell me "In your template at some point you will already pull the the src of your returned thumbImage so all you have to do in your else clause is to create a dummy thumbImage object with the static src http://myapp.com/default.png" what does it mean? Can you quote a small example please. Also, I have tried returning the static path in the else part but it didn't work out. Can you please elaborate the next step after accessing the image?

Comment: I don't know exactly which meteor packages you are using (if any) and how your `ThumbFiles` collection docs look like so I cannot give a working example for that. What I mean is that `thumbImage` in your case is an object and objects in general have attributes and/or methods. One of these will generate or return the image source. This attribute or method is it what you need to override in your `else`. In your template you probably will have a part where the <img> elements get generated or their `src` - this is the point where you should see the method/attribute which is used for it.

Comment: If you are stuck with that you can update your question and add some parts of your template from where we see how an actual image (so not the dummy) gets rendered. And you could also add a mongo document from your `ThumbFiles` collection so that we see its structure.